# use python to get a bar chart of wireshark information

Tags: python, pcap, plotly

I have a pcap file which I want to visualize in Python as a bar chart.

I create a bar chart but I can't get any info on it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.plotly as py
dictionary = plt.figure()
D = {u'Label0':26, u'Label1': 17, u'Label2':30}
plt.bar(range(len(D)), D.values(), align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(D)), D.keys())
plot_url = py.plot_mpl(dictionary, filename='mpl-dictionary')
```

Any clues?